# How to stabilize loss when using keras for image classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Am using keras to perform image classification, I have 10 classes and ~900 image each, I used `VGG 16` and built on top of that this small network

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

am training with `50 epoch`

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get the below accraucy and loss

```
[INFO] accuracy: 94.72%
[INFO] Loss: 0.45841544931342115
```

yet am not sure how to stabilize the loss, should I increase the epochs or there would be other parameters I need to change ?

[image: accuracy and loss]

Answer (score 0):

Due to the val loss fluctuates from first epochs, I think that you forget to freeze the main VGG model and just train your adding Dense stack layers.
Indeed It's better to use 2D Global Ave Polling instead of flattening.

If problem don't solve try to use more efficient pre-trained CNN architectures such as MobileNet V2 or Xception